# Are there any issue inheriting from an abstract class and interface where the abstract inherits from base interface

Tags: c#, oop, unit-testing, inheritance, abstract-class

Are there any issue inheriting from an abstract class and interface where the abstract inherits from base interface. The example below is a much cut down just to show the concept. I doing this so that I create a fake class based on IFooRepository and also the FooRepository can reuse all the code in my abstract class (which will be shared by many other classes):

```
public interface IMyRepository<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> GetEntity();
}

public abstract class MyRepository<T> : IMyRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly string _connectionString;

    public virtual T CommonFunction(int Id)
    {
        //do my common code here
    }

    public List<T> GetEntity()
    {
    }

}

public interface IFooRepository : IMyRepository<Foo>
{
    void UpdateFoo(int id, string foo);
}


public class FooRepository : MyRepository<Foo>, IFooRepository
{
    public void UpdateFoo(int id, string foo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class FakeFooRepository :  IFooRepository
{
    public List<Foo> GetEntity()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UpdateFoo(int id, string foo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IBarRepository : IMyRepository<Bar>
{
    void DoSomethingElse(int id);
}

public class BarRepository : MyRepository<Bar>, IBarRepository
{
    public void DoSomethingElse(int id)
    {

    }
}
```

Also is it better if IFooRepository, doesn't inherit from IMyRepository and instead contains all members like this:

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
    void UpdateFoo(int id, string foo);
    List<Foo> GetEntity();
}
```

Either way the whole thing compiles and works as I expected, just wanted to know if there would be any issues as the interfaces are overlapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example looks very sound. IFooRepository inherits from IMyRepository because that interface is inherently an IMyRepository of type Foo. For that same reason, your second sample where IFooRepository does not inherit from IMyRepository definitely seems to break the relationship you are trying to establish. That does not sound like a good plan.

The other way you might normally consider doing this is to make both Foo and Bar (and T) of a common type (IRepositable or something), and the behavior specific to a Foo or Bar repository is represented in their individual implementation of IRepositable. If this could be done in a way that maintains proper encapsulation of Foo and Bar, you would end up with a very elegant solution.

That would work if Foo needed to do UpdateFoo and Bar, similarly, needed to do UpdateBar using the same method signature, and so on for any other IRepositable. But in your case, the method name DoSomethingElse seems to indicate that IBarRepository is implementing some completely different behavior from the UpdateFoo method. If that's true, then you are correct. The interfaces which inherit from a specific type of of IMyRepository are probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think i will go with the 1st example. I was worried about overlapping interfaces but it looks like that is fine to do as in this example [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement interface in concrete class, if your base class implements some interface then all its' children will be implementors of this interface automatically

Comment: Yes but FooRepository and FakeFooRepository will have different implementations. hence need to implement at top level any shared implementation of the "proper" classes will happen in MyRepository

Comment: In such case the best way is just to define virtual methods with corresponding implementations in your base class and override them if needed. Your FooRepository is IFooRepository because you've derived it from a class that implements that repository, so there is no need to do so.

Comment: Thanks but, I'm not quite sure that works for me as those would be the  CommonFunction in MyRepository but these are only common to the certain classes, but not the fakes (ie FakeFooRepository) as it has a completely separate implementation. hence IFooRepository has what is common to both

Comment: Also just updated the example with a BarRepository too, hope that makes it clearer. Thanks